# sequelize js multi level table casecade join

Tags: database, join, sequelize.js

i'm going to select user detail as table structure.

> Table user columns {user_id, region_id, user_name}
>
> Table region columns {region_id, country_id }
>
> Table country columns {country_id, country_name }

I've join table model as

```
db.user.hasOne(db.region, {foreignKey:"region_id", targetKey:"region_id"});
db.region.hasOne(db.country,{  foreignKey :"country_id", targetKey:"country_id" });
db.user.hasOne(db.country,{through:db.region,otherKey :"country_id", foreignKey :"user_id" });
```

Now i am going  to select user detail contain region name and contain country name here is my controller

```
 models.user.findAll(
   {
    include: [
        {
          model: models.region,
          model: models.country
        }
      ]
});
```

**but this show user not associate with country**

Please save me

Answer (score 1):

it should be multi level join as your schema

```
 models.user.findAll(
   {
    include: [
        {
          model: models.region,
            include:[{model:models.country}]
        }
      ]
});
```

provided that user belongsTo region , region belongsTo country
you can search more about relationships some examples are

> One-to-one relationship: You, as a User, can have one (hasOne)
>   Profile. And of course the inverse also applies. Profile (belongsTo) a
>   User. A user can't have more than one profile and a profile can't
>   belong to multiple users.

Also

> We can define the inverse of a hasOne relationship using the belongsTo method.